# How to store Java class as JSON in MySQL8?

Tags: java, mysql, json, aws-documentdb

In our project we have a need to store some Java objects (with nesting level > 3) as JSONs because structure of this objects are often changed and this is really no convenient to use relational approach to store them.

We were considering different DBs to store objects as JSONs (we are using AWS):

- DynamoDB;
- DocumentDB;
- MySQL 8;

Currently we are considering MySQL 8 as basic option because we are more familiar with this db and it will take less effort to setup it. I was trying to find how to properly store Java objects as JSONs in MySQL 8 and checked this articles:
https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/how-to-handle-json-in-mysql-4adaeeb1d42f
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

But I did not find a way how to store whole class as a JSON, not only one field from some class or String field that will have JSON representation of the class.

So my question is - is that possible to store class like:

```
public class SomeClass {

  private Long id;

  private Instant date;

  private String someInfo;

  private Integer version;

}
```

as JSON without having this class as field in some other class ?

P.S. I don't want to have using of Jackson libraries in my code because developers can add bugs in this part of the code and destroy structure of object to save.

P.S.S.

I understand that I can do something like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class MyClassWrapper {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(name = "json_data",columnDefinition = "json")
    private MyClass myClass;
}

@Data
public class MyClass {

    private Instant date;

    private String someInfo;

    private Integer version;

}
```

My question is is - can I avoid having of MyClassWrapper and save MyClass as JSON directly (without using Jackson library by myself) ?

Comment: Can you not just use Jackson to convert any instance of that class into a json and back? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

Comment: @3Fish I don't want to create some custom JSON mapping logic because there is possibility that developers can create a bugs in this code in the future and structure will be destroyed.

Comment: just use Gson to convert object properties to json, no?  Question is unclear.

Comment: @ago I've clarified question.

Comment: So, you want to save an object as json to your DB without using any json library? I mean, you can write it yourself, but that is even more error-prone than relying on a proven library like jackson or gson.

Comment: I assume you mean to save an object, not a class. It doesn't make any sense to save a class in a database. Why does it have to be JSON? Why not just Java's native `serialize()` and store it in a `BLOB` column in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward solution would be to use Jackson or Gson to convert any object into a json String or Byte[]. These can then be saved to your DB. restoring them is as easy as reversing that process.
Here are some simple examples, `saveDataToDB(String, Sring):void` and `loadDataFromDB(String):String` are placeholders for whatever you need to do to save or load to your database.

```java
//can be created globally and reused every time
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public void saveObjToDB(String id, Object obj)
{
    String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(myResultObject);
    saveDataToDB(id, jsonStr);
}

public <T> T loadObjFromDB(String id, Class<T> clazz)
{
    String jsonStr = loadDataFromDB(id);
    return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, clazz);
}
```

Or with Gson:

```java
//can be created globally and reused every time
Gson gson = new Gson();

public void saveObjToDB(String id, Object obj)
{
    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(myResultObject);
    saveDataToDB(id, jsonStr);
}

public <T> T loadObjFromDB(String id, Class<T> clazz)
{
    String jsonStr = loadDataFromDB(id);
    return gson.fromJson(jsonStr, clazz);
}
```

The default configuration should already work for most classes, and in most cases only complex nesting or generics need more configuration. But even then, the mapper/gson class can be supplied as Singleton globally so that the configuration is done only once and therefore developers don't have to touch this all the time.